# How can I publish an exectuable file to my Azure Function from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, exec

I have a Function App solution with multiple functions that I usually publish from my Visual studio to the cloud. I now need to add an executable file to my Function App so my differents functions can call it. I was able to add the exe file with its dll to the solution and call it locally. Then when I publish my solution, i do not see the executable in any path (siteroot/home....) or the Kudu. The only way I was able to make run an executable in the cloud, was by creating a new Function App and upload directly the exec and code the function in the cloud editor.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your file in Visual Studio and check its properties.

[image: Properties]

Set `Copy to Output directory` to `Copy if newer`.

Or, you could verify your Project's csproj file and include it manually using:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="{filename}">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**EDIT:**

To customize the destination path or even the file name, you could use [build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio. In the **Post-build event** command line box, specify the following:

```
copy /Y "$(SolutionDir){sourceFilename}.{extension}" "$(TargetDir){destinationFilename}.{extension}"
```

There are various macros available for post-build events that you can choose from:

[image: VS Macros]

Comment: Hey this works. I am now having an issue with the DLL being in the BIN folder and not in the same place as the executable file. Do you know how I could fix this? I want them to be both in the same directory. Is there a way to specifiy the location when publishing?

Comment: @Justin Updated my response. Check if that works for you.

Comment: I would like to copy the executable in the bin folder where the DLLs are. Can you guide me please?

Comment: Copying the DLL from the bin to the wwwroot could also be an option

Comment: @Justin As shown above, configure a post-build event as: `copy /Y "$(SolutionDir){sourcefilename}.exe" "$(TargetDir){destinationfilename}.exe"`. Adjust the command as per your project's folder structure.

Comment: Here is what I have:  copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)AAA.exe" "$(TargetDir)bin\AAA.exe" and 
copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)AAA.dll" "$(TargetDir)bin\AAA.dll". Both files goes in the bin folder of the release path in my local, but when i go into the kudu, the executable is still not there. What is the right path for the publish?

Comment: @Justin Sry I couldn't get back sooner here. Is this still an issue?